# How to control alignment of DataTable inside of a PanelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, datatable, alignment, panelgrid

I've got a multi-column panelGrid setup, with dataTables as each of the columns.  Each of the dataTables is a different length.  This results in the panelGrid stretching out to fit the largest dataTable (so far, that's good).  The remaining dataTables are centered vertically (this is not good as it looks horrible on screen) instead of being top justified.

How can I tell panelGrid to top-justify contents?  Or, is my approach completely wrong and I need to do something different (if so, suggestions are welcome)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSF renders as HTML and can be styled with CSS. Inspect the element as follows:

1. View the JSF page in a browser.
2. Right-click the page.
3. Choose *View Source*.

The `<h:panelGrid>` renders an HTML `<table>` element; the `<h:dataTable>` renders as an HTML `<table>` element, as well. The data elements are nested inside the `<td>` element, rendered by the `<h:panelGrid>`. So, set the `vertical-align` of the `<td>` of the `<h:panelGrid>` to `top`.

Assuming that the `<h:panelGrid>` has an `id` which ends up as `<table id="panelGridId">` in HTML, use the following CSS:

```
#panelGridId>tbody>tr>td { 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

## Forms

If the grid is part of a form, then the CSS will need to include the form's ID. For example:

```
<form id="amazingForm">
  <h:panelGrid id="amazingGrid">
    ...
  </h:panelGrid>
</form>
```

The CSS will resemble:

```
#amazingForm\:amazingGrid > tbody > tr > td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

## Example

Here's an example HTML document that shows vertical alignment working within a table configured using CSS:

```
<!-- language: html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3547485</title>
        <style>#myid>tbody>tr>td { vertical-align: top; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myid">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><table><tbody><tr><td>n1a</td></tr><tr><td>n1b</td></tr></tbody></table></td>
                    <td><table><tbody><tr><td>n2a</td></tr></tbody></table></td>
                    <td><table><tbody><tr><td>n3a</td></tr><tr><td>n3a</td></tr><tr><td>n3c</td></tr></tbody></table></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

All get aligned to top. Without the rule, all get centered. It's hard to tell what rule exacty you need to apply since it's unclear how your generated markup look like.

## Tutorials

See also:

- [HTMLDog CSS tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/)
- [CSSTutorial.net](http://csstutorial.net)

Comment: OK, got it working.  I ended up sticking the <style> element directly into the head section of my xhtml file and using the alignment for all td elements.  Unable to get it to work at all if in our CSS file (despite other things coming through fine, such as colors).  Also, unable to restrict it to just the particular td elements that needed it.  Fortunately in this case it's safe to apply to all td on the page.  Thank you very much for your help!  This has been an extremely frustrating problem!

Answer (score 6):

you can use CSS to make the panelgrids to top align.

```
.mystyle {
vertical-align: top;
horizontal-align: center;

}
```

include in your xhtml files.

```
<link href="#{resource['css:style.css']}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and add this code in parent panelgrid.

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="mystyle, mystyle, mystyle">
```

Note:for 3 columns you hav to include it 3 times

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid applying it to every td, only inside panelGrid and datatable inside that.
I had the same problem and the following worked for me:

```
.pgstyle td{ 
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Where *pgstyle* is the styleClass you give  to every panelGrid contains a datatable, like:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="pgstyle">
<rich:dataTable ..>
 ....
</rich:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```