# JSF panelgrid alignment to top

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I see there are some answers posted for this. tried almost all of them with several permutation-combination.. but nothing seems to be working.

components inside panelgris are always middle aligned, instead of top.

tried whatever they said in the below post.
[How to control alignment of DataTable inside of a PanelGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547485/how-to-control-alignment-of-datatable-inside-of-a-panelgrid)

Please let me know if there is a remedy.

Comment: What CSS have you tried? What's the generated markup? Do you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 33):

The `<h:panelGrid>` renders a HTML `<table>` element. The vertical alignment of a table cell `<td>` defaults indeed to `middle`. You want to make it to be `top` instead. This is easy with CSS.

```html
<h:panelGrid styleClass="foo">
```

with

```
.foo td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you have a table inside the panelgrid for which you'd like to keep the default table cell vertical alignment of middle, then you need to alter the CSS as follows:

```
.foo>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

so that only the panelgrid's own table cells are top aligned.

To learn all about CSS, check http://www.csstutorial.net.

Comment: Hi, I added the code as follows, tried both the options you mentioned, but still not able to make it work.
<h:head>
<style type="text/css">
.foo>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
</h:head>



<h:panelGrid id="topalign" columns="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10"
     width="980" styleClass="foo">
what is the mistake am i doing ? The panelgrid has 2 primefaces panel within it as follows.
<p:panel header="Job Detail"
      style="width:680px; border-style: none;">
<p:panel header="Check your Details:"
 style="width:300px; border-style: none;">

Comment: They aren't working for me, either. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `panelGrid`'s `columnClasses` attribute to identify a CSS class that includes the `vertical-align: top;` style:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="topAligned">
...
</h:panelGrid>
```

and the CSS file:

```
.topAligned {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The contents of the first column in the panelGrid will then be top-aligned within their cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use the styleClass for the panelGrid as in the following example code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2"  styleClass="top-aligned-columns" cellpadding="5" style="display:block" cellspacing="5"> 
    <p:outputLabel value="#{resources['IDNumber']}" />
    <p:inputText id="txtIDNumber" value="#{applicantBean.personal.idNumber}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Then in the css configure as follows:

```
.top-aligned-columns td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

With this method you will be able to not only top-align the rows but you can also apply the  same styleClass to other panelGrids within the encompassing panelGrid.

For example:

```
   <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="top-aligned-columns" cellpadding="5" style="display:block" cellspacing="5">
        <p:panel id="pnlApplicant" header="#{resources['ApplicantHeader']}" styleClass="no-border">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="display:block" cellspacing="5" styleClass="top-aligned-columns">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{resources['IDNumber']}" />
            <p:inputText id="txtIDNumber" value="#{applicantBean.personal.idNumber}"  >
                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="tvQuickScore"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{resources['Name']}" />
            <p:inputText id="txtFirstname" value="#{applicantBean.personal.firstName}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{resources['Surname']}" />
            <p:inputText id="txtSurname" value="#{applicantBean.personal.lastName}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>  
</h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: I have tried using the vertical-align: top style instruction and it does not seem to work even when I put it in every h:panelGrid that I am using. There is something buggy in JSF2 or CSS.